# Moving multiple controls in Winforms runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building a runtime designer for Winforms. The goal of this designer is to move controls in their container (e.g. a Form or a Panel).

When I move one control at a time everything work perfect. When I select multiple controls, things go wrong, but not always:
When I select two Buttons, the move works OK, but when I select a Label and a TextBox, the label moves in the wrong direction.

Here is an example what happens: https://www.screencast.com/t/sPaH4VNr

Here's my code:

```
    protected virtual void ControlMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            IsMouseDown = true;
            Point startPosition = Control.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            OffsetMove = new Point();
            OffsetMove.X = Control.Location.X - startPosition.X;
            OffsetMove.Y = Control.Location.Y - startPosition.Y;
        }
        else
        {
            IsMouseDown = false;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void ControlMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Control.Cursor = IsMovable && IsMoveAllowed(e) ? Cursors.SizeAll : Cursors.Default;

        if (IsMouseDown && this.Control.Cursor == Cursors.SizeAll)
        {
            foreach (var control in Parent.SelectedControls.Select(sc => sc.Control))
            {
                Point newPoint = control.PointToScreen(e.Location);
                newPoint.Offset(OffsetMove);

                if (control.Location != newPoint)
                {
                    control.Location = newPoint;

                    control.Parent.Invalidate();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I hope someone sees what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.